# PHP "file_put_contents" does not append to file

Tags: php

I'm having a bit of trouble here. I've created a form that takes data from a text field and (is supposed to) write the data to the end of a .txt file.

However, using `file_put_contents` simply overwrites whatever was in the file beforehand with the submitted data. I'm not sure why this is happening, as I've used this before without fail.

PHP Code:

```
$line = "Name: " . $name . "---" . "Question: " . $question;
file_put_contents('questions.txt', $line . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: Could you give us more info? this code must work fine, try to add `LOCK_EX` after file append and check if its work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe some another script is using your file too. Add `LOCK_EX`:

```
file_put_contents('questions.txt', $line.PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

If it still doesn't work, use `fopen` and `fwrite`:

```
$myfile = fopen("questions.txt", "a");
fwrite($myfile, "\n". $line);
fclose($myfile);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. In my case, I had 2 file_put_contents in different files, in one of them I had FILE_APPEND and in the second file not. The issue was solved adding FILE_APPEND to both file_put_contents functions.